# Private/Protected variable "error: within this context"

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, private, public

I have a class based off of the SFML gamefromscratch.com tutorials, called "VisibleGameObject" Within this class, is a private variable "_sprite", as well as a "getSprite()" function that I tried as both protected and public. (Even as public, it still says "_sprite" is private even though the public function returns the variable).

In my OnRender class, I create two VisibleGameObjects.

```
VisibleGameObject _testtile1;
VisibleGameObject _cursorSprite;
```

But when I draw to draw the sprites, I get the error: within this context.

```
_mainWindow.draw(_cursorSprite._sprite);
```

alternatively I tried (with getSprite() being protected or public).

```
_mainWindow.draw(_cursorSprite.getSprite());
```

Yet always, "error: 'sf::Sprite VisibleGameObject::_sprite' is private. error: within this context"

Doesn't make any sense to me, because

1) _sprite is a variable of VisibleGameObject. It may be private, but it is not being accessed by anything but its own original class of "VisibleGameObject". I thought classes could access their own variables, even when they're a new instantiated object in another class?

2) getSprite() is public, and returns the private variable, yet it is STILL saying _sprite is private? This makes no sense to me! Everything I have learned about Getters and Setters, says that the public function CAN return a private variable, as that is the whole point of this Getter.

```
sf::Sprite& VisibleGameObject::getSprite()
{
return _sprite;
}




class VisibleGameObject
{
public:
VisibleGameObject();
virtual ~VisibleGameObject();

 private:
sf::Sprite  _sprite;



protected:
sf::Sprite& getSprite();
```

OR

```
public:
sf::Sprite& getSprite();
```

Comment: O.....k... sometimes I believe my compiler is buggy. I just tried to make getSprite() public, and now it works. Still doesn't work as Protected though, or making _sprite Protected. And I still don't understand why _sprite can't be accessed by its own object class.

Answer (score 2):

Protected members of a class can only be accessed by the class itself and classes which are derived from it.

Since you are calling the draw function not from within a class that was derived from VisibleGameObject you get an error.

You propably should read this:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/